# If loop calculation to all records

Tags: r

I have some noisy data with numbers, nulls and characters. I need to check the percentage change in numbers. 
For that, I used a regular expression to check the `%` symbol present in a column. `If` yes, then `extract` numbers and subtract the percentage change `Else` `extract` numbers and perform calculations to get change.

Below is the reproducible code

```
df = data.frame(Actual = c('0.10%','55.10%',NA,'20.8B'),
                 Previous = c('-0.50%','47.90%',NA,'16.6B'))
df

  Actual Previous
1  0.10%   -0.50%
2 55.10%   47.90%
3   <NA    <NA>
4  20.8B    16.6B

# if loop to calculate percentage change
if(grepl("%", df$Actual) & grepl("%", df$Previous)) {
   a = as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(df$Actual,"[-\\d.][\\d]"))
   p = as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(df$Previous,"[-\\d.][\\d]"))
   df$Gain = a - p
 } else {
   a = as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(df$Actual,"[-\\d.][\\d]"))
   p = as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(df$Previous,"[-\\d.][\\d]"))
   df$Gain = (a - p)/p * 100
 }

df

  Actual Previous Gain
1  0.10%   -0.50%  0.6
2 55.10%   47.90%  7.2
3   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
4  20.8B    16.6B  4.2
```

The last value should be calculated as 25.30, instead of 4.2
The value of if loop is :

```
grepl("%", df$Actual) & grepl("%", df$Previous)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

The last row should be in else loop. Can you help to get mistake in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `parse_number`-function from the `readr`-package (one of the `tidyverse`-packages) in combination with an `ifelse` condition to achieve what you want.

Using:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(gain = (parse_number(Actual) - parse_number(Previous)) / 
           if_else(grepl('%', Actual), 1, parse_number(Previous)/100) )
```

gives:

> ```
>   Actual Previous    gain
> 1  0.10%   -0.50%  0.6000
> 2 55.10%   47.90%  7.2000
> 3   <NA>     <NA>      NA
> 4  20.8B    16.6B 25.3012
> ```

Comment: This is working. I changed code to 
df %>% 
  mutate(gain = (parse_number(Actual) - parse_number(Previous)) / 
           if_else(grepl('%', Actual), 1, parse_number(Previous)*.01) )

Thank You!

Comment: @Rahulkg007 for that you have to divide the `parse_number(Previous)` in the `if_else` by `100`; I've updated my answer

Comment: This solution is different and quick. I was trying to do in other way. 
I still don't know why if loop didn't work.

Comment: @Rahulkg007 I mentioned this in my answer :) Only the first element (True) is used in your loop

Answer (score 1):

Non-dplyr approach could be

```
df = data.frame(Actual = c('0.10%','55.10%',NA,'20.8B'),
                Previous = c('-0.50%','47.90%',NA,'16.6B'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df


percChange <- function(x) {
  if (all(grepl("%", x))){
    d <- diff(rev(as.numeric(gsub("[^-\\d{1,2}.\\d+]", "", x, perl = TRUE))))
  }
  else {
    n <- rev(as.numeric(gsub("[^-\\d{1,2}.\\d+]", "", x, perl = TRUE)))
    d <- diff(n) / n[1] * 100
  }
  return (d)
}


df$diff <- apply(df, 1, percChange)

df

  Actual Previous    diff
1  0.10%   -0.50%  0.6000
2 55.10%   47.90%  7.2000
3   <NA>     <NA>      NA
4  20.8B    16.6B 25.3012
```

Also, regarding what is wrong with your loop - running it throws the following error:

```
Warning message:
In if (grepl("%", df$Actual) & grepl("%", df$Previous)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Meaning that only the first element (which is `TRUE` because the first row has % values for both columns) will be used. So your outcome in row 4 is `20-16 = 4`! You have to loop over the rows to prevent this

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The function with apply works perfect. :)